# JavaScript Inner-workings Explanation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on trying to understand the inner workings of this piece of JavaScript.

```
var vm = require('vm');
const util = require('util')


payload1 = "this.ref.constructor.constructor('return console')().log('Testing 1')";
payload2 = "this.constructor.constructor('return console')().log('Testing 2')";

context = { ref: {} };
try {
        result1 = vm.runInNewContext(payload1, context);
        result2 = vm.runInNewContext(payload2, context);
}
catch(e) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(e);
}
```

On NodeJS v0.10.29, payload1 executes and payload2 does not. It errors saying **console is not defined**. I have a general idea of why that would be the case due to a change in the vm module in future versions of node, but I don't understand what is different about the two payloads.

To me, both of the payloads are accessing an objects constructor which is a function and then accessing the functions constructor which allows you to build a function with various arguments. In this case the function would return and instance of console, which we execute and then access the console's log function. Why can one of the payloads return the console object and the other not?

It would make sense to me if they both failed in v0.10.29 and then both worked in future versions but that isn't the case. Again I'm more interested in the different between the two payloads than the interaction with the vm module. The script was just an exercise.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Node 0.10.29 is almost 6 years old; it's ancient by Node standards.

Comment: I know, thats why I'm not really interested in anything other than why the two payloads behave differently. For the sake of understanding the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both snippets access a native `Function` constructor function. The difference is that `payload1` accesses it on the `ref` object which is passed from outside into the vm, and is the global `Function` builtin of the calling code - which of course also has `console` available as a global. In contrast, `payload2` accesses it on the global `this` value inside the vm environment, and gets the `Function` constructor of the vm environment - which evaluates the `return console` code inside the vm scope as well, where no `console` was defined.

To simplify, you should be able to achieve similar results with

```
demo = { log(x) { console.log(x + " from outer"); } };
payload1 = "f('return demo')().log('Testing 1')";
payload2 = "Function('return demo')().log('Testing 2')";
context = { f: Function, demo: { log(x) { console.log(x + " from inner"); }}};
```